# Размещение элементов в GridLayout

Tags: android

Имеется такая проблема. Есть GridLayout в котором явно указано количество строк и столбцов.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="4" />
```

Элементы добавляются динамически следующим образом.

```
GridLayout.Spec column = GridLayout.spec(value);
GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(value);
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, column);
gridLayout.addView(view, params);
```

Вся проблема состоит в том, что при добавлении элемента в ячейку с номером к примеру 3,3 (а так же это происходит при других значениях ячеек не равных 0,0) добавление происходит в указанную ячейку но представление отображается на месте ячейки 0,0 вместо своей ячейки. После добавление второго представление в ячейку 0,0 (или в соседние ячейки) сетка выравнивается и элементы расставляются по своим местам, то есть первый добавленный элемент начинает отображаться на своем месте (сдвигается с ячейки 0,0 в свою) и второй добавленный элемент на своем месте. Вся проблема состоит в том, как реализовать добавление таким образом что бы элементы изначально отображались в ячейках в которые они добавлены, а не фактически в случайном месте и по ходу заполнения GridLayout выравнивались и начинали отображаться на своих местах. Да еще все добавляемые представления имеют один размер.

Answer (score 0):

Это костыль, но можно как решение рассмотреть: можно создать заполненную таблицу, только сделать все ячейки invisible. Соответственно по мере добавления ячеек менять видимость. Рассмотрите также recyclerview с gridlayoutmanager